# Не получается передать данные из ajax запроса в action контроллера

Tags: php, ajax, yii

Код ajax запроса:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { confirm: 'dfsfdsfsd' },
                url: "<?php echo $this->createUrl('article_tag/update'); ?>",
            });
```

По какой-то магической причине `$_POST['confirm']` не существует в `Article_tagController->actionUpdate()`.
Есть у кого какие идеи, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Для начала нужно убедиться, что запрос доходит до этого экшена. Именование article_tag и Article_tagController неверное. Должно быть ArticleTagController и article-tag/update

Comment: После 1)url не оставляй запятую ,2) в actionUpdate напиши че нибудь (echo 1111). 3) Смотри в  Console->Network->Response если увидишь свой 1111 то все в порядке,Меняй jquery библиотеку.если нет убедись что путь до actionUpdate прописан правильно

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({ confirm: 'dfsfdsfsd' }),`

Comment: Запрос до экшена должен доходить тк путь рабочий. К тому же этот путь указан в form action и все ок. Сам экшен тоже рабочий. Даже не знаю к чему можно еще придраться

Comment: Была таже проблема, для POST, PUT надо сначала в строку конвертировать. + `'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf8'`

Comment: E_p, не понял что за PUT, а с `'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf8'` на странице отображается только html код